# Reboot Linux Device via Posh-SSH

Tags: linux, powershell, ssh, posh-ssh

I am trying to reboot Linux machine from PowerShell script running on Windows 10.
I use Posh-SSH module. All other commands I send via SSH session work fine, but reboot has no effect no matter what I tried. 
Via regular SSH client session (Putty or BitWise) these commands work and device reboots immediately.
Below is a sample command:

```
Invoke-SSHCommand -SSHSession $session -Command "nohup reboot >/dev/null &" -EnsureConnection
```

I tried with/without nohup. 
Tried shutdown -r,  reboot, reboot -f.
Tried using exit command
Tried sleep/timeout.

All these worked as expected in SSH console, but nothing worked via Posh-SSH.
What am I missing that's different in Posh-SSH?

Comment: PowerShell 6 has Restart-Computer. Have you installed PowerShell 6 on the Linux machine? https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell

Comment: I can't - it is embedded Linux distro, barely have required commands there

Comment: Perhaps there will come a time when pwsh is included in Linux distros just as they do bash, ksh, tcsh, etc...

Answer (score 1):

Finally I managed to get it working by using stream.
Below is code snippet. Start-Sleep is needed before you close the stream, otherwise there's not enough interval for it to run.

```
$stream=$session.Session.CreateShellStream("ps", 0, 0, 0, 0, 1000)
$stream.WriteLine("reboot")
Start-Sleep 1000
$stream.Close()
```